# java socket InputStream hangs/blocks on both client and server

Tags: java, sockets

I am recently working on a tiny program aimed to close the browser remotely. The basic procedures are as follow:

Server side:

1. Create a SocketServer to listen to some certain port.
2. Accept a connection and create a corresponding socket object
3. Read the InputStream from the created socket(blocked on this operation)

Client side:

1. Create a socket object to establish a connection with the server.
2. Send the command to close the browser on Server side by writing bytes to OutputStream.
3. Read the feedback from the server by using read() on InputStream of the socket(blocked on this operation)

Code below:

**Server.java**

```java
package socket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Server {

    private static ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        InetAddress targetAddress = null;
        NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByName("eth2");
        System.out.println(ni);
        Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = ni.getInetAddresses();
        while(inetAddresses.hasMoreElements()) {
            InetAddress inetAddress = inetAddresses.nextElement();
            if(inetAddress.toString().startsWith("/10")) {
                targetAddress = inetAddress;
                break;
            }
        }
        ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket(11111, 0, targetAddress);
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Server is running...");
            Socket client = sSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client at: " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            es.execute(new ClientRequest(client));
        }
        
    }
}
```

**ClientRequest.java**

```java
package socket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClientRequest implements Runnable {

    private Socket client;
    
    public ClientRequest(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        
        try {
            System.out.println("Handled by: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            // get input/output streams for client socket
            InputStream cis = client.getInputStream();
            OutputStream cos = client.getOutputStream();
            
            // buffer size : 1024 ?
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int recvSize;
            int totalRecvSize = 0;
            while(-1 != (recvSize = cis.read(buffer, totalRecvSize, 1024 - totalRecvSize))) {
                totalRecvSize += recvSize;
            }
            
            String command = new String(buffer, "utf-8");
            System.out.println("Command from client: " + command);
            
            String commandNative = CommandMap.getNativeCommand(command.trim());
            if(null != commandNative) {
                Process np = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandNative);
                InputStream is = np.getInputStream();
                byte[] bufferProcess = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                int totalBytesRead = 0;
                while(-1 != (bytesRead = is.read(bufferProcess, totalBytesRead, 1024 - totalBytesRead))) {
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                }
                // give feed back of process output
                cos.write(bufferProcess);
                
                // close process input stream
                is.close();
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(null != client) {
                try {
                    client.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and finally, **Client.java**

```java
package socket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class Client {

    private static final int BUF_SIZE = 1024;
    
    // feedback message size will not exceed 1024 bytes
    private static final byte[] BUFFER = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        
        Socket socket = new Socket("10.117.37.176", 11111);
        System.out.println("Connected to Server...");
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        
        String command = "kill ie";
        byte[] commandBytes = command.getBytes(Charset.forName("utf-8"));
        
        System.out.println("Send: " + command);
        os.write(commandBytes);
        System.out.println("After send: " + command);
        
        int totalRecv = 0;
        int recvSize;
        
        while(-1 != (recvSize = is.read(BUFFER, totalRecv, BUF_SIZE - totalRecv))) {
            totalRecv += recvSize;
        }
        
        String feedback = new String(BUFFER, "utf-8");
        System.out.println("Feedback: " + feedback);
        
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

To reiterate the problems:

- The server side can not read the command by calling read(buffer, offset, len) on InputStream object of the socket. It blocks.
- The client side can not read the feedback by calling read(buffer, offset, len) on InputStream object of its socket. It blocks.
- But when I comment out the feedback reading operations in Client.java, both server and slient work correctly.

I am wondering what's the hidden causes in this code?

Answer (score 12):

Your socket reading code is reading until EOF.  you will not receive EOF until you close the socket.  hence, your code never proceeds.

if you only want to send a single command on the socket connection, then close the OutputStream after writing the command (using `Socket.shutdownOutput()`).

If you want to send multiple commands on a single socket connection, then you will need to come up with a way of delimiting each command ([simple example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11588369/552759)).

Comment: Thanks for you great answer ! But one problem still exists, Client wants to get some feedback, in my case, the feedback should be the output of the native command(aims to close the browser). If I add os.close(), when I called read() method on InputStream, a SocketException will be thrown with message "socket closed", how I can handle this issue ? Many thanks.

Comment: @destiny1020 - did you try my suggestion?  closing the outputstream is independent of closing the inputstream.

Comment: Yes, I have tried your suggestion, I add one line os.close(), after os.write() in Client.java. But there is one exception when I tried to call in.read() method: Socket closed, maybe close the underlying OutputStream will indirectly close the socket connection ? I am confused on this. Thanks for your reply !

Comment: I close the output stream with its own close() method, actually socket.shutdownOutput() should be called instead, I have figured it out. Thanks for you suggestion, it rocks!

Comment: @destiny1020 - ah, sorry about that, will update my answer.  i thought that closing the outputstream directly was the way to do that.  been awhile since i worked with sockets.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading until EOS at both ends, which is a poor choice, as you can't 'send' the EOS without losing the ability to send further data on the same connection. You need to redesign your application protocol so you can read a command at a time without requiring that the connection be closed to complete it. For example, send lines, or a length word prefix, or a self-describing protocol such as XML or Java Object Serialization, or whatever you can read via DataInputStream without relying on EOFException.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, indeed there are some design problems in my application. Many thanks.