# Socket - Bad OutputStream output (Funky Question Marks)

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

With the code below, I'm not getting "daSHI" printed onto the console. 
Instead im getting "?????" printed.

To test, instead of using the socket's input/output streams, I created a FileInputStream and FileOutputStream writing/reading from the same file and "daSHI" was printed just fine.

However, when I use sock.getOutputStream and sock.getInputStream, it doesn't work for some reason. All I'm getting are question marks. Any ideas? Encoding Problems?

```
public void sendMessage(Socket sock) throws KVException {

    OutputStream outStream;
    InputStream inStream;

    try{

        byte[] b = {'d', 'a', 'S', 'H', 'I'};
        outStream = sock.getOutputStream();

        outStream.write(b);
        sock.shutdownOutput();



        inStream = sock.getInputStream();

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("" + (char) inStream.read());
         }

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        KVMessage errorMessage = new KVMessage("resp", "Network Error: Could not send data");
        throw new KVException(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a loopback socket connection?  You haven't shown how the socket is connected to the other end.  What's at the other end echoing the data?

Comment: Random guess:  The input stream is at EOF, and that is just 5 times -1. Omit (char) to verify. Why? Depends on your server... Did you try adding outStream.flush() and closing the socket only after you have read data from input?

Comment: Your `socket` InputStream is not the same as `OutputStream`. So, why d you expect the data to echo back?

Comment: I created a socket through 'new Socket("localhost", 'portnumber')

How would I be able to send things through the inputstream and for some receiver to get that input then? Apparently, im thinking about this the wrong way.

Comment: @StefanHaustein Like add .flush() after the .write() and .shutdownOutput() after the reading? When I do this, it seems like it just hangs. 

I read on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189338/java-socket-inputstream-hangs-blocks-on-both-client-and-server) that the socket keeps reading until EOF, which I won't get until I close the socket. Therefore, I have to close it before reading?

Comment: @GermannArlington Misunderstood Sockets/Input&Output Streams in general.

Comment: Look up echo port number - http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml - and connect to that port (echo service is active by default). Generally, always remember that for TCP connection to work it needs `ServerSocket` on one end and `Socket` on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're connected to an echo server or another copy of the same application, sockets don't work that way: you can't expect to read what you wrote because what you're reading is what the far end of the socket is sending.

Most likely, the cause here is that the input stream has hit EOF and `read()` is returning -1.  -1 becomes a [zigamorph](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/Z/zigamorph.html) when cast to `char`, and printing this invalid character produces a `?`.