# Socket messaging between Java Client and Python Server

Tags: java, python, sockets

I try to create a Socket messager between a Java Client and Python Server. It works to send a message *("Testdata")* from client to server and print it out. But after input and send a message from server to client, I get no output from client. The client 'freezes' and must be terminated.

What is the problem with my client input?

---

**Terminal Server:**

```
py socketServer.py
Connection from: ('127.0.0.1', 57069)
from connected user: Testdata
> Test
send data..
```

**Terminal Client:**

```
java socketClient   
Testdata
```

---

**Python-Server:**

```
import socket

def socket_server():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 35100

    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
    server_socket.listen(2)
    conn, address = server_socket.accept()
    print("Connection from: " + str(address))
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        if not data:
            break
        print("from connected user: " + str(data))
        data = input('> ')
        conn.send(data.encode())
        print("send data...")
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket_server()
```

**Java-Client:**

```
private static void socketTest(){
    String hostname = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 35100;

    try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port)) {
        OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, false);

        BufferedReader input =
                new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text;

        do {
            text = in.nextLine();
            writer.print(text);
            writer.flush();
            System.out.println("from server: " + input.readLine());
        } while (!text.equals("exit"));

        writer.close();
        input.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can look over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913440/connecting-python-socket-and-java-socket) answer. ( @carlos palma )

Comment: Your client is reading lines but your server isn't sending lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because python messages are not explicitly finished with `\r\n` like @carlos palmas says in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913440/connecting-python-socket-and-java-socket) answer.